# Countdown Timer using functional component in ReactJS doesn't work properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, countdowntimer

I want to make a countdown timer with start, stop, resume and reset buttons. However, I could not figure out why my code does not work. I am guessing that the issue lies in the part on timer, setInterval and clearInterval.

I have attached snippets of my code below.

Help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
function Countdown() {

    const [ timerRunning, setTimerRunning ] = useState(false);
    const [ startTime, setStartTime ] = useState(0);
    const [ totalTime, setTotalTime ] = useState(0);

    var timer;

    const startTimer = () => {
        setTimerRunning(true);
        setStartTime(totalTime);
        setTotalTime(totalTime);
        
        timer = setInterval(() => {
            const remainingTime = totalTime - 1000;
            if (remainingTime >= 0) {
                setTotalTime(remainingTime);
            } else {
                clearInterval(timer);
                setTimerRunning(false);
                setStartTime(0);
                setTotalTime(0);
            }
        }, 1000);
    };

    const stopTimer = () => {
        clearInterval(timer);
        setTimerRunning(false);
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to  put your `setInterval` in `React.useEffect` take a look at this [post](https://sebhastian.com/setinterval-react/)
some suggestions for your code:

- use className instead of class attribute in your elements.
- don't use var or let in react functional components.

Answer (score 0):

useState doesn't change value immediately. So it's value is not actually changing. To avoid this use `UseEffect` hook.

```js
useEffect(() => {
        let intervalid
      if (timerRunning){
          intervalid = setInterval(() => {
            const remainingTime = totalTime - 1000;
            if (remainingTime >= 0) {
                
                setTotalTime(remainingTime);
            } else {
                clearInterval(intervalid);
                setTimerRunning(false);
                setStartTime(0);
                setTotalTime(0);
            }
          }, 1000);
      }

    
      return () => {
        clearInterval(intervalid)
      }
    }, [timerRunning,totalTime])
```